# 13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at new <anonymous> (ui-grid.js:3332) at Object.invoke

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am trying to use UI grid from my angular application but i am getting below error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (ui-grid.js:3332)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4718)
    at S.instance (angular.js:10354)
    at p (angular.js:9263)
    at angular.js:9673
    at angular.js:16383
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17682)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17495)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:17790)
    at l (angular.js:11831)
```

HTML:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptionsGeneral" class="myGrid"></div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.gridOptionsGeneral = {};
            $scope.gridOptionsGeneral = {
                enableFiltering: true,
                data: res,
                columnDefs: [
                     { field: 'Col1' },
                     { field: 'Col2' },
                     { field: 'Col3' },
                     { field: 'Col4' },
                     { field: 'Col5', enableFiltering: false},
                    { field: 'data1', enableFiltering: false},
                    { field: 'data2', enableFiltering: false},
                    { field: 'data3', enableFiltering: false}
                ],
                onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                }
            };
```

res here is the response which i am getting through an http call. Ironically, same piece of code works when i call it from another controller but fails for this controller.

Comment: The data binding is happening before your http call returns, which causes it to bind to `res = null`.

Comment: So how do we make sure that the data binding happens after the http call ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your `httpget` that populates the data, you will have to modify my answer to fit your code:

```
$scope.res = [];
$scope.gridOptionsGeneral = {};
$scope.gridOptionsGeneral = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    data: $scope.res,
    columnDefs: [
    { field: 'Col1' },
    { field: 'Col2' },
    { field: 'Col3' },
    { field: 'Col4' },
    { field: 'Col5', enableFiltering: false},
    { field: 'data1', enableFiltering: false},
    { field: 'data2', enableFiltering: false},
    { field: 'data3', enableFiltering: false}
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
       $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};


$http.get(url, config)
.then(
   function(response){
      //success call
      $scope.res = response.data;
   }, 
   function(response){
     // failure call back
   }
);
```

The above will define res as an empty array which will cause the current code to show an empty grid. By having the `res` variable on the scope it will be watched for changes. When the `httpget` finishes, the success call is fired and rebinds `$scope.res` and your grid will be notified and updated as well.